# Best way to gather ActiveRecord date attributes for timeline graphing purposes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm kind of lost on this one. I could build up a bunch of count queries to find all records which have a last login date for a given period, like count how many for each day in the past week (7 count queries, one for each day), but I'm interested in knowing if there's a nifty, more efficient Ruby/Rails way to do this.

I don't really have any sample code to post. Maybe something like this will help:

```
hour_range = 7 * 24 # 7 days worth of hours
start_date = Time.now.to_time - day_range
end_range = Time.now
start_date.to_date.upto(end_range.to_date) do |day|
    # Series of count queries which populate an array of counts for each day...
end
```

I'm using Highcharts (or trying it out) to chart the graphs on the client side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan ahead, you can create derivative columns in your table that can be indexed. That makes grouping the results together pretty straightforward.

For instance, if you want to group by day, create a Date column. If you want to group by week you can do that using some of the date functions available to you, producing values like `201204` for the 4th week of 2012. Month is even easier as that's just `%Y%M` formatted dates.

Most of these can be populated either as a separate migration on existing data using native SQL date formatting functions, or as a series of `before_save` hooks.

The way to make reporting efficient and responsive is to do the smallest number of queries possible, and to make those queries as easy for the DB to compute as possible. Loading in hundreds of records or making dozens of queries is not going to scale.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm good on the date column. The Model objects have the last_signed_in date column already. I was looking for suggestions, but I expected some commentary on, "loop and query count for each day" vs "query with a single date only select, and sort them into days in ruby then count them yourself" Maybe with some Ruby magic sprinkled in. ;)

Comment: Never under-estimate the power of the `GROUP BY` statement.